# convention for drain/source position?

Tags: mosfet

could you please tell me how to determine where the gate-source-voltage would be in this image for both a n-mos and p-mos.

[image: WIN-20181122-21-59-06-Pro]

Comment: is this a school question?

Comment: your question is unclear ..... the gate-source voltage would be between the gate and the source ...... but i am sure that is not what you intended to ask

Comment: Are you asking which end of the FET is the source, for both NMOS and PMOS?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that this mosfet is connected as an analog switch, it is possible for either side to take the role of the source and the drain. The convention for an NMOS is simply:

- The source is the side that has the **lowest** voltage.
- The drain is the side that has the **highest** voltage.

For a PMOS it is the other way around:

- The source is the side that has the **highest** voltage.
- The drain is the side that has the **lowest** voltage.

It is perfectly possible that the drain and source change sides constantly throughout circuit operation.

Comment: Note that this relies on having a four-terminal FET. Three-terminal FETs have their source connected to the bulk, which fixes one side as source and one side as drain.